# Returning incorrect data

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

The autoform is only recording one accept/reject which it applies to all jobOffers. Doesn't doc=this refer to the individual jobOffer when inside an {{#each}} statement.

Path: Schema.js

```
Schemas.Offers = new SimpleSchema({
    offer: {
        type: String,
        optional: true,
        allowedValues: ['Accept', 'Reject'],
        autoform: {
                type: "select-radio",
                options: function () {
                return [
                {label: "Accept", value: 'Accept' },
                {label: "Reject", value: 'Reject' },
                ];
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Path: `template.html`

```
{{#each jobOffers}}

    {{#autoForm collection="Offers" id="offerForm" doc=this type="update" autosave=true}}

        {{> afQuickField name="offer" type="select-radio" template="buttonGroup" label=false}}

    {{/autoForm}}   

{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0):

All forms in your loop uses the same `id='offerForm'` which is what is used to determine the destination.

Fix this by adding a dynamic id to your Autoform.

If `jobOffers` is a cursor from Mongo, it will have a unique `_id` you can use to prefix/postfix on your form `id` with something like `id='offerForm{{_id}}'`

Comment: thanks, I've tried `{{#autoForm collection="JobOffers" id="offerForm{{_id}}" doc=this type="update"}}` but it hasnt work. There's no errors in console either.

Comment: can you check in the DOM/HTML that the id is assigned correctly?

Comment: If I'm reading it correctly it's returning `id="offerForm{{_id}}"`

Comment: ia it translating the _id into it's balue is what i meant. it should be something like `offerFormGt3usJg86b67` or whatever..

Comment: Yeh, i think it's actually printing id="offerForm{{_id}}" . Do I need to create a helper or hook to get _id

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to create a helper.

Path: `helper.js`

```
Template.Offer.helpers({
    jobOffers: function () {
        return JobOffers.find({candidateUserId: Meteor.userId()});
    }, 
    makeUniqueID: function () {
      return this._id;
    }
});
```

Path: `template.html`

```
{{#each jobOffers}}
    {{#autoForm collection="JobOffers" id=makeUniqueID doc=this type="update"}}
        {{> afQuickField name='offer'}}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit">Update</button>
    {{/autoForm}}   
{{/each}}
```